# nmap show port is closed even though I opened it

Tags: centos, firewall, nmap

My VPS is running on CentOS 7.2 , I opened a port by `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8006/tcp --permanent` and have already type the `firewall-cmd --reload` command, but when I check the port by nmap,  nmap -p 8006 ip-addressxxx, it still shows it is closed. Here is some information may help:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status firewalld
 ● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-04-07 02:06:50 EDT; 3 days ago
 Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 663 (firewalld)
 CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
       └─663 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid

 Apr 07 02:06:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
 Apr 07 02:06:50 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
 Apr 10 02:03:42 localhost.localdomain firewalld[663]: ERROR: ALREADY_ENABLED: 80:tcp
 Apr 10 02:03:49 localhost.localdomain firewalld[663]: ERROR: ALREADY_ENABLED: 8006:tcp
```

.
.
.

```
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
target: default
icmp-block-inversion: no
interfaces: ens3
sources: 
services: dhcpv6-client ssh
ports: 8009/tcp 80/tcp 8080/tcp 8006/tcp
protocols: 
masquerade: no
forward-ports: 
sourceports: 
icmp-blocks: 
rich rules:
```

.
.
.

```
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --list-ports
8009/tcp 80/tcp 8080/tcp 8006/tcp
```

.
.
.

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -plunt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         
State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      992/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::8009                 :::*                    LISTEN      1027/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                   LISTEN      1383/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                   LISTEN      1027/java           
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                  LISTEN      992/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8006          :::*                    LISTEN      1027/java
```

Answer (score 1):

**Revisited my answer**

The process you have listening on port 8006 is only listening on the loopback interface, `127.0.0.1`, it should be listening on `0.0.0.0`. See the sshd process in your process list `0.0.0.0:22` it works fine.

Use something like `netcat` to test. This will open a port on `8006` on the `0.0.0.0` interface, which is open to the world because of your firewall rules

**On your VPS Try:**

`nc -l 8006`

and then scan with nmap again and you will see the port is open, provided your firewall rules are in place.

You want to see this in the process list

`tcp6       0      0 0.0.0.0:8006          :::*                    LISTEN      1027/java`

and not

`tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8006          :::*                    LISTEN      1027/java`